# Sorting a paginated table built with KnockoutJS by column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm trying to figure out how to sort a table by clicking on the column header. I tried creating a method in my ViewModel that will just sort by name to get started, but have had no success.

I tried the following, but it didn;t seem to actually do anything:

```
list.sort(function(left, right) { return left.name== right.name? 0 : (left.name< right.name? -1 : 1) })
```

Here's my current code:

http://jsfiddle.net/TsgyJ/

For example, I'd like to click on "name" header and have it sort Ascending, then click again and have it sort Descending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working sample for your: http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/TsgyJ/1/

Html:

```
  <thead>
    <th data-bind="click: sort.bind($data, 'id') ">ID</th>
    <th data-bind="click: sort.bind($data, 'name') ">Name</th>
    <th data-bind="click: sort.bind($data, 'email') ">Email</th>
    <th data-bind="click: sort.bind($data, 'city') ">City</th>
    <th data-bind="click: sort.bind($data, 'created') ">Created</th>
  </thead>
```

JavaScript:

```
self.sort = function (key) {
    sortDir = sortDir * -1;
    self.list.sort(function (a, b) {
        return sortDir * (a[key] == b[key] ? 0 : (a[key] < b[key] ? -1 : 1));
    });
    self.moveToPage(1);
};
```